# Finding number of solutions for a trigonometric equation.

Tags: trigonometry

How exactly would one go about solving the following math question. I know the answer is 3 but I don't get how to arrive at this answer. A step by step explanation is greatly appreciated. Please keep in mind that I'm only a high school sophomore before you throw in any fancy trig. And i dont believe that it requires math outside of what we learnt which is pretty basic high school trig.

**State the number of solutions of the equation cos(x) - sin(2x) = 1, for 0 ≤ x ≤ 2π.**

cos(x) - sin(2x) = 1

=> cos(x)(1-2sin(x))=1

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First try to find the solutions  over $\mathbf R$, then select those which in $[0,2\pi]$.

Set $t=\tan \dfrac x 2 (x\not\equiv\pi\mod 2\pi)$. The restriction on the values of $x$ is unimportant, as one checks these values are no solutions of the equation. We know that
$$\cos x=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},\quad\sin x=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}.$$
Replacing in $\,\cos x(1-2\sin x)=1$ leads us, after some simplifications, to:
$$2t^2(t-1)^2=0\iff \begin{cases}t=0\\t=1\end{cases}$$

Now

- $t=\tan\dfrac x2=0\iff \dfrac x2\equiv 0\mod\pi\iff x\equiv 0\mod 2\pi$,
- $t=\tan\dfrac x2=1\iff \dfrac x2\equiv \dfrac\pi 4\mod\pi\iff x\equiv \dfrac\pi 2\mod 2\pi$.

In the prescribed interval, we find only three solutions:
$$x\in\Bigl\{0,\,2\pi,\,\frac\pi 2\Bigr\}$$

Comment: Hmmm... I didn't want to give him the full answer. Nevertheless, good answer! +1 from me.

Comment: @Kugelblitz i tried what u suggested before i posted the question but it simply i didn't get anywhere. Bernard i understood your explanation but i didn't get how you knew to set t = tan(x/2).

Comment: @guest It's okay! I'm not complaining as to why you didn't accept my answer or upvote it! That's your wish and your opinion. Also, Bernard used a convenient representation of the trig terms, so that it is easier to find the solutions using algebra. It takes practice to make effective substitutions like that, and a lot of exposure to trig problems will help in gradually building up experience to realise when and where to make substitutions in trig equations.

Comment: @Kugelblitz k thnx for taking the time even though i didn't upvote u, btw that is because im not a complete member yet and i can't upvote or down vote yet. sorry!

Comment: Haha. No problem man! Welcome to MSE!

Comment: @Kugelblitz: as the method is comparatively non-standard, I suspected the question was a little tough for the O.P., and thought it would be more useful to explain in detail.

Comment: ^Exactly what I realized later. Hence I gave the +1. But for some reason the OP has accepted my answer now o.O Edit: Glad to see that your answer has been accepted now. Wonder why the transition...

Answer (score 0):

$$cos(x) - sin(2x) = 1$$
$$cos(x) - 2sin(x)cos(x) = 1$$
$$cos(x)(1 - 2sin(x)) = 1$$

If both factors in an expression multiplied are each one, then they result in one; fortunately, one solution is already found here => $$x = 0$$

Convert cos(x) into terms of sin(x)[Hint: $cos^2(x)=1- sin^2(x)$], and then find the rest of the solutions for yourself in that interval by evaluating the equation. (Evaluate it like you'd do with an algebraic expression, but now within that specific interval...)

Comment: "If both factors in an expression multiplied are each one, then they result in one". This is false.

Comment: I mean if a=1 and b=1, the expression ab will be 1. How is it false?

Comment: @BernardMassé Please do explain how it is false.

Comment: Why was my answer accepted? o.O Bernard's answer is clearly better! It gives a helpful trick as well as the right solutions...@guest I think you need to accept his answer and not mine; his is clearly more helpful to you!

Comment: $4\times\frac{1}{4}=1$ but neither of the factors are 1.

Comment: ^ I SAID IF THEY BOTH THEMSELVES ARE ONE -_- IF a=1 and b=1 then ab = 1 -_- Please read the post carefully sir...