# Counting number of solutions in an interval to an aperiodic trig function

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I am trying to solve a larger problem and I am stuck at a step which involves analyzing aperiodic, but always differentiable, trig functions.

It seems fairly straightforward to count (or at least very closely approximate) the number of solutions to a trigonometric function within an interval if the function has a regular, predictable period within the interval.

This even applies to functions that are not perfect sinusoids and functions that have varying amplitude. For example,

$f(x)=cos(x)-2sin(x)$
[image: y=cos(x)-sin(2x)]
[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1168890/finding-number-of-solutions-for-a-trigonometric-equation) does a good job of answering how to find how many roots there are in an interval $[a,b]$ for this function.

But now, what if the trig function has a dynamically changing period or no period at all over the interval?

Consider:

$f(x)=sin(\frac{200}{x})$
[image: y=sin(200/x)]
or even more complex,

$f(x)=cos(\frac{x+100}{x})cos(x+101)$
[image: y=cos((x+100)/x)cos(x+101)]

Assuming that $f(x)$ is always differentiable at all points within $[a,b]$,
is there an analytical, non-iterative way to count or approximate the number of solutions of $f(x)$ contained in the interval?

By analytical and non-iterative, I mean without plotting the function on a graph or creating a table and iterating.

I am already using these types of iterative methods, but they are quite time consuming for intervals with lots of solutions. My best method so far is to manually compute all values of the argument function within the interval which are multiples of $\pi$ or other relevant trigonometric constants. As you can see, such a table can be quite large for, say, $sin(\frac{200}{x})$ on $[1.5,2]$

This is not ideal because the actual locations/values of the solutions are irrelevant to me, yet I am forced to compute them anyway. I am only interested in counting the number of solutions in the interval; I couldn't care less about precisely where they are located.

Alternatively, I have found another way to solve the larger problem if I am able to find the absolute maximum and/or minimum of an aperiodic trig function within an interval.

So I am looking for a way to either

- count the number of solutions to such a function in $[a,b]$
- or find the location of the absolute minimum and/or maximum of the function in $[a,b]$

**without manually counting, iterating, or graphing (i.e., purely formulaic)**

I am very afraid this isn't possible or it's one of those pesky "unsolved problems". But anything is better than manually counting. All help is appreciated.